# How can I convert a PEM key into a RSA key pair?

Tags: ssh

I was just sent a PEM key from a client as a means to access their Amazon EC2 instance. How do I convert this into something I could use with OpenSSH?

Comment: Does this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011572/convert-pem-key-to-ssh-rsa-format) help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract a PEM public key from an OpenSSH private key using:

```
openssl rsa -pubout -in .ssh/id_rsa
```

But OpenSSH has no tools to convert from or too PEM public keys (note: PEM
private keys are OpenSSH's native format for protocol 2 keys)

Answer (score 2):

If you were just sent the private key in the form of `keyfile.pem` (e.g. for Amazon LightSail VPS) then you can just use it directly as an ssh private key:

```
ssh -i keyfile.pem ubuntu@dest_ip
```

Or you can add it to your agent like this:

```
ssh-add ./keyfile.pem
```

And then login:

```
ssh ubuntu@dest_ip
```