# Can I use an SSH key generated on Linux from Putty?

Tags: ssh, windows, putty

I have been asked to generate a pair of SSH keys so that I can access a remote server for development.  To generate the keys, I used the `ssh-keygen` tool on our CentOS box, which I successfully did.

Now I have 2 files: `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, `~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub`. I will give the admin the `.pub` file so that he can place it on the remote server.  However, I want to use my own personal windows PC (using PuTTY) to access this remote server.

So my question is this: even though I generated the SSH keys on a Linux server (that has no relation whatsoever to the remote server and my pc), can I still access the remote server with my Windows PC using the private key that was created?

The reason I'm a little unsure is because while I was creating the keys, it said "The key fingerprint is: xxxxxxxx" which made me think that since the "fingerprint" is CentOS's fingerprint, it won't let me use the private key on my Windows machine. Am I right that it won't work, or as long as I have the private key it doesn't matter what machine I use to log in to the remote server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.linux-sxs.org/networking/openssh.putty.html) you can convert your `dsa` keys to a format that PuTTY will accept with a PuTTY tool, PuTTY Key Generator.

There is more detail on this page which describes [importing your RSA or DSA key](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/PuTTY-rsa-dsa-keys/) into  PuTTY format. Essentially, you just select 'Import Key' from the 'Conversions' menu and navigate to where the key is stored on your machine.

Comment: I see.  So the fact that the machine using the private key was not the original machine that generated it doesn't matter?

Comment: That is my understanding, but I've never used PuTTY. I have however, moved SSH keys between Linux machines without any issues whatsoever.

Comment: @paulsmith that is correct (about it not mattering). If it helps, try not to think of ssh keys as identifying the machine, but rather identifying the user.