# Convert Amazon .pem key to Putty .ppk key Linux

Tags: ssh, linux-mint, security, putty, amazon-ec2

I have generated and downloaded a private `.pem` key from AWS. However, to use Putty in order to connect to the virtual machine, I must have that key in `.ppk` format. The process of conversion is detailed in roughly 20 lines here:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/get-set-up-for-amazon-ec2.html#prepare-for-putty

I am using Linux Mint (an Ubuntu distro) and I know I can use puttygen in the terminal. However, I have no idea how to use this tool, nor how to configure the needed parameters. When I type puttygen --help I get

```
PuTTYgen unidentified build, Aug  7 2013 12:24:58
Usage: puttygen ( keyfile | -t type [ -b bits ] )
                [ -C comment ] [ -P ] [ -q ]
                [ -o output-keyfile ] [ -O type | -l | -L | -p ]
  -t    specify key type when generating (rsa, dsa, rsa1)
  -b    specify number of bits when generating key
  -C    change or specify key comment
  -P    change key passphrase
  -q    quiet: do not display progress bar
  -O    specify output type:
           private             output PuTTY private key format
           private-openssh     export OpenSSH private key
           private-sshcom      export ssh.com private key
           public              standard / ssh.com public key
           public-openssh      OpenSSH public key
           fingerprint         output the key fingerprint
  -o    specify output file
  -l    equivalent to `-O fingerprint'
  -L    equivalent to `-O public-openssh'
  -p    equivalent to `-O public'
```

But I have no idea whatsoever on how to do what the website tells me to do and all my tentatives failed so far.

How do I do what the website tells me to do, using puttygen on the terminal?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74545/what-difference-between-openssh-key-and-putty-key/74560#74560

Answer (score 71, accepted):

#### Using the GUI

See this SO Q&A on how to do exactly what you want, titled: [Convert PEM to PPK file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190667/convert-pem-to-ppk-file-format).

*excerpt*

1. Download your .pem from AWS
2. Open PuTTYgen, select Type of key to generate as: SSH-2 RSA
3. Click "Load" on the right side about 3/4 down
4. Set the file type to `*.*`
5. Browse to, and Open your .pem file
6. PuTTY will auto-detect everything it needs, and you just need to click "Save private key" and you can save your ppk key for use with PuTTY

#### Using the command line

If on the other hand you'd like to convert a `.pem` to `.ppk` file via the command line tool `puttygen`, I did come across this solution on SO in this Q&A titled:

- [How to convert SSH keypairs generated using PuttyGen(Windows) into key-pairs used by ssh-agent and KeyChain(Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use).

*excerpt*

```
$ puttygen keyfile.pem -O private -o avdev.ppk
```

For the public key:

```
$ puttygen keyfile.pem -L
```

#### References

- [Converting Your Private Key (Putty)](http://support.cdh.ucla.edu/help/132-file-transfer-protocol-ftp/583-converting-your-private-key-)

Comment: steps 2 to 6 also work for other private key file types (e.g. resulting file from a Git Bash ssh-keygen command), thanks!

Comment: doesn't work anymore from the command line

Comment: Any thoughts on how this would work on OSX, PuTTYgen isn't available

Comment: If you want to add a password/passphrase to the private key, just add `-P`. E.g. `puttygen k.pem -PO private -o k.ppk`.

Comment: For me it worked from command line!

Comment: Of course putty-gen does not have a GUI on Linux. Be aware also that it is less tolerant of stray whitespace.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using GNU/Linux, you don't have to use Putty. That part of the tutorial is geared towards Windows users.

Just set your `.pem` file permissions to `r--` by doing `chmod 400 mykey.pem` then you can pass it straight to ssh :

```
ssh -i mykey.pem user@aws-host.amazon.com
```

Comment: The reason I am trying to use putty is so I can follow the instructions in this [plex tutorial](http://infoliser.com/how-to-install-plex-media-server-on-a-centos-6-x-server-and-enable-internet-access-using-ssh-tunneling-with-putty-and-firefox/). If there are other ways of doing it, then please feel free to explain.

Comment: Your Plex Media server is on the AWS machine and you're trying to tunnel to it from your Mint workstation, am I getting this right ? You should open another question explaining this, but there are already many questions explaining how to do SSH tunneling.

Comment: By using the command that you mentioned i was able to login in to the remote AWS instance. I actually wanted to transfer files i used the command (just in case it helps someone) `sftp -oIdentityFile=mykey.pem user@<publicIP>` ... thanx your post helped me solve the problem i was having for more than 5 hours.

Answer (score 0):

use the below command its worked for me in ubuntu

`puttygen /home/abc/Downloads/dockerkey1.pem -o home/abc/Downloads/dockerkey1.ppk -O private`

**Example**

`puttygen pemKey.pem -o ppkKey.ppk -O private`

Comment: This is already described in the accepted answer. You don’t need to use `sudo` for this, if your current user has write permission in the output directory.

Comment: Thanks For your Suggestion @Stephen kitt