# How to add a phrase-less key to ssh agent?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

On running the command `ssh-add mykey.ppk` it asks for passphrase:

> Enter passphrase for `mykey.ppk`:

But I can see that the key does not have any passphrase and is not encrypted

```
$ head mykey.ppk
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: imported-openssh-key
Public-Lines: 6
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC8V+PLuklXrfFDZ9GNluXB/L8foOzaEp5s
jwaOL1iAxCKDWWsfsmyj9MbhV5r4Z6VGo/0T
```

Simply pressing enter at the prompt does not work. How can I add this key to the agent?

PS: I've already heard the sermon on security practices, so you can save your breath :-)

Comment: Did you just cat your private key to the entire internet?

Comment: I never seen that file format outputted, so I don't know. So, that's why I'm asking

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I would think so, that looks very short for an RSA key.

Comment: Relax guys. This is a putty key where the first section of the file is public key and length is 2048 bits. What you're seeing is a truncated public key. Its more of a `head` of the file than a full `cat`

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74545/what-difference-between-openssh-key-and-putty-key and cross-stack http://superuser.com/questions/990275/generate-rsa2-key-in-openssh-format and http://superuser.com/questions/989826/generate-rsav2-key-in-openssh-format-in-windows

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ssh-agent` does not support private keys in PPK format (PuTTY). You need to convert the key to OpenSSH key using PuTTY gen to be able to add it to your `ssh-agent`.

Related question on [RaspberryPi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/50863/34307).

These steps are needed:

- Load your private key into PuTTYgen
- Go to **Conversions → Export OpenSSH** and export your key as `mykey.key`
- Add your key to your agent using `ssh-add mykey.key`.

On Linux, the equivalent `puttygen` command is:

```
puttygen mykey.ppk -o mykey.key -O private-openssh
```